# How to get playlists created by my app

Tags: android, file, playlist

I have this piece of code

> ```
>         final ContentResolver resolver = this.getContentResolver();
>         final Uri uri = MediaStore.Audio.Playlists.EXTERNAL_CONTENT_URI;
>         final String idKey = MediaStore.Audio.Playlists._ID;
>         final String nameKey = MediaStore.Audio.Playlists.NAME;
>         final String[] columns = { idKey, nameKey };
>         final Cursor playLists = resolver.query(uri, columns, null, null, null);
> ```

This returns to me, all the playlists found on the device. However I want only those playlists which are created by my application, not all playlists created in other places. The problem is I dont find any `created_by` or sthg like `MediaStore.Audio.Playlists.created_by`.

Comment: store all playlist names in hashmap  created by your app and then , get all the playlist from hashmap

Comment: yeh problem is, if user uninstalls and installs the app again.

Comment: store playlist names  on firebase and then get the playlist name from firebase

Comment: could you please mark it as answer?